How to pass remaining options to another class?
What is the good way to pass remaining options to another class?
\begin{filecontents}{main.cls}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\newcommand{ \selectedoptions } { color }

\keys_define:nn { class / options } {
  theme .choices:nn = { bw, color, dark, draft } {
    \renewcommand{ \selectedoptions } {
      \tl_use:N \l_keys_choice_tl
    }
  }
}

\ProcessKeyOptions[class / options]

\LoadClassWithOptions{ article } % How to pass all options 
                                 % except the theme one?

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, theme=bw]{main}
%\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}

NOTE
The options will be chosen to never have the same name as another class because the setting done by the other class will never be used by the main one.

I hope you don't use this just because you're getting an Unused global option(s): [theme] warning. If that's the case, there are simpler (or other?) solutions to that (though I don't find the relevant question right now...).

I am learning to use class options; so I am making bad things even if it works more or less.

Indeed, the solution given by Joseph Write with the setting given by cfr does the job without any warning.

It might work, but it will gobble up any option you define in your class that has the same name as in article. So if you added a 12pt option to your class, article's 12pt option wouldn't fire anymore.

I have updated my question. I will always avoid name clashing.

well, I can't really delete the answer, as I guess you know.

As mentioned in clsguide, you can pass unknown options using a built-in command:
\DeclareUnknownKeyHandler[class/options]{% This line was edited by projetmbc.
  \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}%
}

Thus anything you do not declare can be passed on.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

@projetmbc but is it still true that anything not declared will be passed on? is unknown-to-class/options equivalent to not-declared-by-class/options in general?

@cfr My idea is to add options to another class. That is the job of the other class to say "I don't know this option". It is not my problem if something like \documentclass[bidon]{article} can't compile silently, as far as I know.

If your objective is to load article with all options and you're only setting up this strange filtering to avoid an Unused global option(s): [theme] warning you can use the following simple solution. Else look at any of the other blocks in this answer (or other answers).
expkv-opt has different macros to parse options with different behaviour regarding the unused global options list. In particular in a class file the usage of \ekvoProcessLocalOptions would add any unknown option to said list and remove any known option from that list. However if you're using \ekvoProcessGlobalOptions you basically get the same options (since the global options are the options handed to \documentclass and since your class is the main class), but the behaviour differs. \ekvoProcessGlobalOptions only removes from the unused options list, it never adds to it.
With this behaviour you can simply forward all options to article (which will fill the unused options list), and afterwards parse them through \ekvoProcessGlobalOptions which will remove all options known to your class from the unused options list. No filtering necessary.
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{main.cls}
\ProvidesExplClass{main}{2024-11-01}{1}{adhoc class for an MWE}

\LoadClassWithOptions { article }

\RequirePackage{expkv-def,expkv-opt}

\newcommand*\selectedfontsize{10}

\ekvdefinekeys { class / options }
  {
     choice-store~     theme = \selectedoptions {bw, color, dark, draft }
    ,initial~          theme = color
    ,protect~ noval~   12pt  = \renewcommand*\selectedfontsize{12}
  }

\ekvoProcessGlobalOptions { class / options }
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, theme=bw, foo]{main} % added foo so we get an unused global options warning
%\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\selectedfontsize

\blinddocument

\end{document}

Unfortunately this approach isn't possible with ltkeys, afaik, since it either removes from the unused options list if you didn't specify an unknown handler and adds the unknown options to it, or if you provide an unknown handler to ignore the unknown options it won't remove the known ones from the unused options list.
The only way to make this work with ltkeys is either if you don't have any options with the same names as article-options in your class, or if you define all the options that do using .code:n = <whatever you want to do>\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}. That last thing is possible, but you lose all key handlers that don't support arbitrary user code (so no .int_set:N for instance). So it'd look like this:
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{main.cls}
\ProvidesExplClass{main}{2024-11-01}{1}{adhoc class for an MWE}

\newcommand \selectedoptions { color }
\newcommand \selectedfontsize { 10 }

\keys_define:nn { class / options } {
  theme .choices:nn = {
    bw,
    color,
    dark,
    draft
  } {
    \exp_args:NNV \renewcommand \selectedoptions \l_keys_choice_tl
  }
  ,12pt .code:n =
    \renewcommand\selectedfontsize{12} \PassOptionsToClass{12pt}{article}
}
\DeclareUnknownKeyHandler[class/options]{%
  \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}%
}

\ProcessKeyOptions[class / options]

\LoadClass{ article }
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, theme=bw, foo]{main}
%\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\selectedoptions\selectedfontsize

\blinddocument

\end{document}


Since you only define a theme key the easiest solution is to use the unknown .code:n to forward all the unknown options.
Unfortunately l3keys doesn't provide some interface to distinguish opt={} from opt, so the code here assumes that every empty value is an option given without a value.
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{main.cls}
\ProvidesExplClass{main}{2024-11-01}{1}{adhoc class for an MWE}

\newcommand \selectedoptions { color }

\keys_define:nn { class / options } {
  theme .choices:nn = {
    bw,
    color,
    dark,
    draft
  } {
    \exp_args:NNV \renewcommand \selectedoptions \l_keys_choice_tl
  }
  % as noted in Joseph's answer you can (and should) use
  % `\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}` here if you're only using
  % this key set in \ProcessKeyOptions.
  ,unknown .code:n = \exp_args:Ne \PassOptionsToClass
    { \l_keys_key_str \tl_if_empty:nF {#1} { = { \exp_not:n {#1} } } }
    {article}
}

\ProcessKeyOptions[class / options]

\LoadClass{ article }
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, theme=bw]{main}
%\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}


If you have more than just one key and part of them should be forwarded you have to somehow filter out the keys that shouldn't get forwarded. For this the following defines a little helper macro that does string based comparison to a single key name that gets removed from an input key=value list.
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{main.cls}
\ProvidesExplClass{main}{2024-11-01}{1}{adhoc class for an MWE}

\newcommand \selectedoptions { color }
\newcommand*\selectedfontsize{10}

\keys_define:nn { class / options } {
  12pt .code:n = \tl_set:cn { selectedfontsize } { 12 } % just to get a second key
  ,theme .choices:nn = {
    bw,
    color,
    dark,
    draft
  } {
    \exp_args:NNV \renewcommand \selectedoptions \l_keys_choice_tl
  }
}

\ProcessKeyOptions[class / options]

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__projetmbc_filter_kv:nn { nv }
\cs_new:Npn \__projetmbc_filter_kv:nn #1#2
  {
    % \keyval_parse:nnn will return each kv-pair in \exp_not:n, we need a step
    % more
    \use:e
      {
        \keyval_parse:nnn
          { \__projetmbc_filter_kv_aux:nn {#1} }
          { \__projetmbc_filter_kv_aux:nnn {#1} }
          {#2}
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__projetmbc_filter_kv_aux:nn #1#2
  { \str_if_eq:nnF {#1} {#2} { , \exp_not:n {#2} } }
\cs_new:Npn \__projetmbc_filter_kv_aux:nnn #1#2#3
  { \str_if_eq:nnF {#1} {#2} { , \exp_not:n {#2={#3}} } }

\exp_args:Ne \PassOptionsToClass
  { \__projetmbc_filter_kv:nv { theme } { @raw@opt@\@currname.\@currext } }
  { article }

\LoadClass{ article }
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, theme=bw]{main}
%\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\selectedfontsize

\blinddocument

\end{document}


This is an example using expkv-def and expkv-opt instead of ltkeys.
Since expkv-def has the very handy also mechanism that allows adding arbitrary code to any predefined code handler it is rather simple to add key-forwarding to a list of keys. The following does that using a \clist_map_inline:nn loop for the key 12pt.
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{main.cls}
\ProvidesExplClass{main}{2024-11-01}{1}{adhoc class for an MWE}

\RequirePackage{expkv-def,expkv-opt}

\newcommand*\selectedfontsize{10}

\ekvdefinekeys { class / options }
  {
     choice-store~     theme = \selectedoptions {bw, color, dark, draft }
    ,initial~          theme = color
    ,protect~ noval~   12pt  = \renewcommand*\selectedfontsize{12}
    ,protect~ unknown~ code  = \PassOptionsToClass{#1={#2}}{article}
    ,protect~ unknown~ noval = \PassOptionsToClass{#1}{article}
  }

% specify all defined keys that should be forwarded
\clist_map_inline:nn { 12pt }
  {
    \ekvifdefined { class / options } { #1 }
      {
        \ekvdefinekeys { class / options }
          { also~ protect~ code~ #1 = \PassOptionsToClass { #1 = {##1} } { article } }
      }
      {}
    \ekvifdefinedNoVal { class / options } { #1 }
      {
        \ekvdefinekeys { class / options }
          { also~ protect~ noval~ #1 = \PassOptionsToClass { #1 } { article } }
      }
      {}
  }

\ekvoUseUnknownHandlers*
\ekvoProcessLocalOptions { class / options }

\LoadClass{ article }
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, theme=bw]{main}
%\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\selectedfontsize

\blinddocument

\end{document}


Another expkv based alternative would be to define two key sets, one filtered and one unfiltered. The advantage of this method is that you can use your key sets outside of option parsing (so in a normal \mainsetup macro or the like) to change options later in the document.
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{main.cls}
\ProvidesExplClass{main}{2024-11-01}{1}{adhoc class for an MWE}

\RequirePackage{expkv-def,expkv-opt}

\newcommand*\selectedfontsize{10}

% if you also want to have a normal set for the options for a `\setup`-macro
% this allows that transparently to the user. If you don't need this the
% following four lines can be removed.
\ekvredirectunknown { class/options }
  { class/options/filtered, class/options/unfiltered }
\ekvredirectunknownNoVal { class/options }
  { class/options/filtered, class/options/unfiltered }

\ekvdefinekeys { class/options/filtered }
  {
     choice-store~     theme = \selectedoptions {bw, color, dark, draft }
    ,initial~          theme = color
  }
\ekvdefinekeys { class/options/unfiltered }
  {
    ,protect~ noval~   12pt  = \renewcommand*\selectedfontsize{12}
  }

% rules to forward an unknown key. Always forward to article, and if the key is
% known in the unfiltered set also use that (via the *documented* low level
% interface of building the key-macros directly, this is just a bit faster than
% using \ekvset{class/options/unfiltered}{#1} -- and since expkv supports
% expansion notation this could in theory make a difference in strange edge
% cases of key names)
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__projetmbc_forward_key:n #1
  {
    \PassOptionsToClass {#1} { article }
    \ekvifdefinedNoVal { class/options/unfiltered } {#1}
      { \use:c { \ekv@name { class/options/unfiltered } {#1} N } }
      {}
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__projetmbc_forward_key:nn #1#2
  {
    \PassOptionsToClass {#1={#2}} { article }
    \ekvifdefined { class/options/unfiltered } {#1}
      { \use:c { \ekv@name { class/options/unfiltered } {#1} } {#2} }
      {}
  }
\ekvoUseUnknownHandlers \__projetmbc_forward_key:n \__projetmbc_forward_key:nn
\ekvoProcessLocalOptions { class/options/filtered }

\LoadClass{ article }
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, theme=bw]{main}
%\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\selectedfontsize

\blinddocument

\end{document}


I have provided a basic example. Thanks for your solution, but is there a generic way with more options treated by l3?

@projetmbc is using a non-L3 package fine as well (so moving away from l3keys)?

If it is not a too TeXian solution, I'm open to it. :-)

@projetmbc I'll try to provide both. Please note that your theme definition was poor, since the value of \l_keys_choice_tl might change throughout your document, you'd need to expand it before assigning the new value to \selectedoptions, see my edit.

Good point for the expansion. I will look at your proposition tomorrow. Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

The original option handler as used by article was designed for simpler times, you just need to give it a bit of help here.
As you know your class has defined a theme option you can simply remove it from the list of options that article classes as unused.
LateX uses the \@use@ption macro to do this whenever an option is handled by a package and the unused global option warning is only given if there are items remaining by \begin{document}  Unfortunately it doesn't take an argument saying which option to remove, it just uses \CurrentOption so you need to locally set that:
\begin{filecontents}{main.cls}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\newcommand{ \selectedoptions } { color }

\keys_define:nn { class / options } {
  theme .choices:nn = { bw, color, dark, draft } {
    \renewcommand{ \selectedoptions } {
      \tl_use:N \l_keys_choice_tl
    }
  }
}


\ProcessKeyOptions[class / options]

\LoadClassWithOptions{ article } % How to pass all options 
                                 % except the theme one?


% if theme is in unknown option list remove it
\def\CurrentOption{theme}\@use@ption\let\CurrentOption\@empty


\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, theme=bw]{main}
\begin{document}

\end{document}

